# iPad 2 multiprocessing?

Tags: ios, ipad, multiprocessing

Does the iPad 2 allow a multi-threaded app to run 2 threads on 2 processor cores simultaneously?

If so, is there anything required, other than queuing up a lock-free background task or GCD block, to get this multiprocessing performance boost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be astounded if you needed to do anything special. Run it in Instruments if you want to be absolutely sure.